# reading HDF5-format MATLAB file in python with h5py

Tags: python, matlab, h5py

I am trying to read a HDF5-format MATLAB file in python, using the h5py library. This file is called "Q_visSDF_accurate.mat" and has two keys: "filename" and "sdf". "filename contains a cell array strings. "sdf" is a  [6001, 49380] matrix containing floats. I had no problem to extract the variable sdf using the following code:

```
import h5py
data = h5py.File("Q_visSDF_accurate.mat", 'r')
sdf = data.get("sdf")[:,:]
sdf = sdf.astype(float)
```

However, I cant read the filename variable. I tried:

```
filename = data.get("filename")[0]
```

but the code returns:

```
array([<HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>,
   <HDF5 object reference>, ..., <HDF5 object reference>,
   <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>], dtype=object)
```

I can I de-reference the containt of the filename variable? Using the hdf5storage package is not a solution, as it works only for python 32 bits and can only read a subset of matlab variables.

Comment: Have you tried using `hdf5storage`?  It can read hdf5-based .mat files into a more usable form.

Comment: I edited my original post accordingly.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm still stuck with your exact problem

Answer (score 1):

In Octave I created a file with cell and matrix

```
>> xmat = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
>> xcell = {1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9};
>> save -hdf5 testmat.h5 xmat xcell
```

In `ipython` with `h5py`, I find that this file contains 2 groups

```
In [283]: F = h5py.File('../testmat.h5','r')
In [284]: list(F.keys())
Out[284]: ['xcell', 'xmat']
```

The matrix group has a `type` and `value` dataset:

```
In [285]: F['xmat']
Out[285]: <HDF5 group "/xmat" (2 members)>
In [286]: list(F['xmat'].keys())
Out[286]: ['type', 'value']
In [287]: F['xmat']['type']
Out[287]: <HDF5 dataset "type": shape (), type "|S7">
In [288]: F['xmat']['value']
Out[288]: <HDF5 dataset "value": shape (3, 3), type "<f8">
In [289]: F['xmat']['value'][:]
Out[289]: 
array([[ 1.,  4.,  7.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  8.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  9.]])
```

The cell has the same `type` and `value`, but `value` is another group:

```
In [291]: F['xcell']['type']
Out[291]: <HDF5 dataset "type": shape (), type "|S5">
In [292]: F['xcell']['value']
Out[292]: <HDF5 group "/xcell/value" (10 members)>

In [294]: list(F['xcell']['value'].keys())
Out[294]: ['_0', '_1', '_2', '_3', '_4', '_5', '_6', '_7', '_8', 'dims']
...
In [296]: F['xcell']['value']['dims'][:]
Out[296]: array([3, 3])
```

I had to use the `[...]` to fetch the value of a cell, since it is a 0d array:

```
In [301]: F['xcell']['value']['_0']['value'][...]
Out[301]: array(1.0)
```

To really replicate the question I should have created string cells values, but I think this illustrates well enough how a cells are stored - as named datasets within a data group.

I'm assuming the Octave h5 storage is compatible with MATLAB's.