# Python: Issue reading in str from MATLAB .mat file using h5py and NumPy

Tags: python, string, matlab, numpy, h5py

I am having difficulty loading in 'str' variables 'Et' (Endtime) and 'St' (Starttime) from a MATLAB .mat file into Python.

I want identical output as in MATLAB. Instead I have had issues trying to solve this. See below for Python code and output.

```
# Import numpy and h5py to load in .mat files
import numpy as np
import h5py 

# Load in Matlab ('-v7.3') data
fname = 'directory/file.mat'
f = h5py.File(fname,'r') 

# create dictionary for data
data= {"average":np.array(f.get('average')),"median":np.array(f.get('median')), \
             "stdev":np.array(f.get('stdev')),"P10":np.array(f.get('p10')), \
             "P90":np.array(f.get('p90')),"St":np.str(f.get('stime')), \
             "Et":np.str(f.get('etime'))}
# All other variables are arrays

print(data["Et"])
```

output:

```
<HDF5 dataset "etime": shape (1, 6), type "<u4">
```

I want to have a string in python equal to the string in MATLAB.
In other words, I want print(data["Et"]) = '01011212000000' which is the date and time.

How can I solve this?

An example of the data in MATLAB:
[image: example]

Comment: At least with Octave 'hdf5' file, `f['average']` has 2 datasets, 'type' and 'value'.  It's a good idea to read both separately.  For a string `type` is `b'sq_string'`, and `value` is a (n,1) array of 'int8' dtype.  That could, I think be cast to a Python `bytestring`.  There have been a few of SO questions that explore loading `hdf5` mat files, though I don't recall if any looked at strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030188/reading-hdf5-format-matlab-file-in-python-with-h5py/43099856#43099856, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300974/opening-a-mat-file-using-h5py-and-convert-data-into-a-numpy-matrix/37305759#37305759, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044613/how-to-import-mat-v7-3-file-using-h5py/46045117#46045117

Comment: What is `f.get('etime')`?  Is it a group or a dataset?  If a group, does it have any keys?

Comment: `f.get('etime')` brings up **<HDF5 dataset "etime": shape (1, 6), type "<u4">**

Comment: Try  `np.array(f.get('etime'))`.  Load it as an array; we might be able to 'decode' it after, as I do in my `In[138]`.

Comment: np.array(f.get('etime')) = [[3707764736          2          1          1          2          1]]

Comment: Let's refine that `np.array(f.get('etime'), dtype='<u4')`.  Or use `bytes` as suggested by `@machnic.

Comment: np.array(f.get('etime'), dtype='<u4') = `[[3707764736          2          1          1          2          1]]`. It has shape (6,1) and 24 bytes.

Comment: I get the following error using the bytes code below: **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 3: invalid continuation byte**. It is still a string and not a char at this point. I am going to try @machnic method now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the variable type of `etime` and `stime` stored in `file.mat` and you can store them as type `char` instead of `string`, you could read them in Python by: `bytes(f.get(your_variable).value).decode('utf-8')`. In your case:

```
data = {
    "average": np.array(f.get('average')),
    "median": np.array(f.get('median')),
    "stdev": np.array(f.get('stdev')),
    "P10": np.array(f.get('p10')),
    "P90": np.array(f.get('p90')),
    "St": bytes(f.get('stime')[:]).decode('utf-8'),
    "Et": bytes(f.get('etime')[:]).decode('utf-8')
}
```

I'm sure there is also a way of reading `string` type, but this might be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Octave

```
>> x = 1:10;
>> y = reshape(1:12, 3,4);
>> et = '0101121200000';
>> xt = 'a string';
>> save -hdf5 testh5.mat x y et xt
```

In a numpy session:

```
In [130]: f = h5py.File('testh5.mat','r')
In [131]: list(f.keys())
Out[131]: ['et', 'x', 'xt', 'y']
In [132]: list(f['y'].keys())
Out[132]: ['type', 'value']
In [133]: f['x/type'].value
Out[133]: b'range'
In [134]: f['y/type'].value
Out[134]: b'matrix'
In [135]: f['y/value'].value
Out[135]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
       [10., 11., 12.]])
In [136]: f['et/type'].value
Out[136]: b'sq_string'
In [137]: f['et/value'].value
Out[137]: 
array([[48],
       [49],
       [48],
       [49],
       [49],
       [50],
       [49],
       [50],
       [48],
       [48],
       [48],
       [48],
       [48]], dtype=int8)
In [138]: f['et/value'].value.ravel().view('S13')
Out[138]: array([b'0101121200000'], dtype='|S13')
In [139]: f['xt/value'].value.ravel().view('S8')
Out[139]: array([b'a string'], dtype='|S8')
In [140]: f.close()
```

[how to import .mat-v7.3 file using h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044613/how-to-import-mat-v7-3-file-using-h5py)

[Opening a mat file using h5py and convert data into a numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300974/opening-a-mat-file-using-h5py-and-convert-data-into-a-numpy-matrix)

====

`bytes` also works in my file

```
In [220]: bytes(f['xt/value'].value)
Out[220]: b'a string'
In [221]: bytes(f['et/value'].value)
Out[221]: b'0101121200000'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When using `list(f['average'].keys())` I get the following error: **AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'keys'**.

Comment: OK, in my version, `f['average']` is a group with 2 datasets.  Apparently in yours `f['average']` is the dataset itself.  I don't have your file so can't explore it myself.

Comment: 'average' is a 9 x 365 matrix containing mostly NaNs with a few floats here and there.

Comment: Digging around I see there's a greater difference between MATLAB v7.3 and Octave's hdf5.  Without a sample file I can't help.

Comment: @hpualj I have added an image of the data in MATLAB. I couldn't find a way to attach a .mat file

Answer (score 0):

When I need to load `.mat` I use `scipy` and it works fine:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('fileName.mat')
```

Comment: Sounds like the OP has saved the .mat with the newer hdf5 mode, not a `loadmat` compatible one.

Comment: I cannot see any string variables when following this procedure. Output: `dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'average', 'stdev', 'median', 'P90', 'P10', 'None', '__function_workspace__'])`

Comment: No Et or St. Note: don't worry about the NaNs - they are supposed to be.